Prisma client error: cannot read properties of undefined
I have a web application built with an express.js backend, PostgreSQL db and use Prisma client. I have 2 separate POST routes in the app, /api/chat and /api/sendRecReview (code below). This web app is hosted on Render.
app.post("/api/chat", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const clientIp = req.ip;
    const timestamp = new Date();
    const messageHistory =
      req.body.messageHistory.map((messageObj) => messageObj.User) || [];

    const answers = req.body.answers;

    console.log(messageHistory);
    const responseObj = await querydb(messageHistory, answers);
    const updatedMessageHistory = req.body.messageHistory.concat({
      AI: responseObj.text,
    });

    // Arrange club recs data to save in database
    const clubData = updatedMessageHistory[1].AI;
    const clubString = clubData.replace("```json\n", "").replace("\n```", "");
    const clubRecsToSave = JSON.parse(clubString);

    // Save IP address, timestamp, and recommendations to the database
    const session = await prisma.session.create({
      data: {
        clientIp: clientIp,
        timestamp: timestamp,
        answers: JSON.stringify(answers),
        recommendations: JSON.stringify(clubRecsToSave),
      },
    });

    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ messageHistory: updatedMessageHistory, clientIp: clientIp });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: "An error occurred while processing the request" });
  }
});

app.post("/api/sendRecReview", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const clientIp = req.ip; 
    const timestamp = new Date();
    const answers = req.body.answers;
    const recommendations = req.body.clubs;
    const rating = req.body.rating;

    const review = await prisma.review.create({
      data: {
        clientIp: clientIp, 
        timestamp: timestamp,
        answers: JSON.stringify(answers),
        recommendations: JSON.stringify(recommendations),
        rating,
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json({ response: "Rating Successful" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: "An error occurred while processing the request" });
  }
});

// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

// Looking for ways to speed up your queries, or scale easily with your serverless or edge functions?
// Try Prisma Accelerate: https://pris.ly/cli/accelerate-init

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Session {
  id              String   @id @default(uuid())
  clientIp        String
  timestamp       DateTime @default(now())
  answers         String
  recommendations String
}

model Review {
  id              String   @id @default(uuid())
  clientIp        String
  timestamp       DateTime @default(now())
  answers         String
  recommendations String
  rating          String
}

When I hit both routes in localhost, the data correctly saves to both the Session table and the Review table in the database. When I run these on the Render hosted site, the data is correctly saved to the Session table but not the Review table. I get the below error telling me review is undefined when I run .create on it.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
at file:///opt/render/project/src/index.js:258:25
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
at next (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:137:5
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
==> Detected service running on port 10000
==> Docs on specifying a port: https://render.com/docs/web-services#port-binding

Migrations have been run and all code has been pushed to Github and deployed to Render. The only slight variation is the Review table was created separately as part of the second migration as where Session was part of the first migration. Can anyone think of why the Review table is not being recognized at runtime on Render but is working fine in localhost?
